# Google cloud dataflow, how custom source works

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to build a custom source by extending BoundedSource using google cloud dataflow APIs. I would like to know how and when the custom source's start() and advance() method will be invoked by dataflow platfrom?
If someone can explain the method invocation flow for custom source, will help alot.

Comment: What have you tried? Try to look at this document first to see how you should ask question and get better answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for [Source.Reader](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/Source.Reader) describes the interactions with the `Reader`.